# lua table global/local var getting confused

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a lua table which I used to share values between files. But I am getting confused in the following case

utility.lua file

```
M = {}
M.host_url = '192.168.0.1'
function M.myFunc()
   print(M.host_url )
end
return M
```

in my main.lua

```
utility = require('utility')
utility.myFunc()   -- this gives me 'a nil value' error
```

I get an error (nil value) for the host_url?

Comment: How are you using that snippet of code? In what environment? Because that literal snippet with a `M.myFunc()` added below it works correctly. Can you show us a more representative sample of the code in use?

Comment: I edited my question again. I used it in another lua file

Comment: i did have return M in the end

Comment: @wildcolor: Then make `M` a local variable (`local M = {}`). You are probably overwriting it in another module.

Comment: @siffiejoe   Thanks very much. It did work. Did you mean I might overwrite M in another module or host_url?

Comment: Either one. Without `local` that `M` variable is a global. Any other module/etc. that uses/creates another `M` variable will use the same global `M` variable and this would cause problems (specifically if you have another module written in exactly that style you would have problems).

Comment: @EtanReisner and siffiejoe    thanks guys. It seems to be the exact problem. I have another module (mydata.lua) that contains another global M table.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Why reusing global `M` may cause the problem? As you see, it is the returned `M` (not global one) that is used in main program.  Returned `M` is saved in `package.preload` and can not be overwritten be another module.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The returned `M` can't be (and the `package.preload` entry won't be) but the global can and will. So anything that uses the global `M` will get the most recent created `M` module (like the use of `M.host_url` in that function since it isn't use `utility:myFunc` calling syntax).

Comment: @EtanReisner - It seems that author is using `M` only inside the code of the module, not in the main program.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff When the `myFunc` function is called what `M` variable does it use internally? And the OP said they have another module using the same pattern.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Thanks, now I see that wrong `M`  )))  Sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff They weren't stupid questions. Seeing what is going on here isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: thanks for all the discussion. @EtanReisner   I did defined another module that is similar as my 'utility.lua' and it also has M inside. However, I only defined one M.host_url which is in 'utility.lua'. It is surprised to see the error. But I do admit that defining two global M s is a bad idea.

Comment: @wildcolor The problem is that the `M` being used inside the `M.myFunc` function is **not** the `M` from that module it is the *global* `M` available whenever the function is called. I'm going to try to write up an answer explaining this later.

Comment: @EtanReisner ah...... of course!!! Thanks. This finally clears up my mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

In M.myFunc doing only print action that function nothing will be return.in your utility file returning whole array see he below code that will clear your doudt.

In main.lua

```
utility = require('util')
value = utility.host_url
print(value)
```

Comment: This works to get the value but doesn't explain or solve the underlying problem.

Comment: can you explain clearly.what is the confusion you are getting ?i am not getting what you are asking?

Comment: @AndroidUser thank you. siffiejoe's answer already solved my question.